# python pyplot xaxis label interval

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to change the interval of the xaxis by using

```
major_ticks = np.arange(0,11,1)
```

but this does not give the result i want
[image]

[image: this is what i would like]

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have dates(datetime) and vals lists. When x-axis is datetime it is more complicated than just using numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter

months = MonthLocator()  # every month
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(dates, vals, '-o')      # x: datetime, y: random % values
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)   # define xtick major location
monFmt = DateFormatter('%Y-%m')      # define xtick string format
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)   # apply xtick location
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monFmt) # apply xtick label
plt.show()
```

Then you will get the following plot. y value are random so it may look different in your plot.

[image]